# Line of code moves to next line after I type semicolon in C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I'm new to **visual studio code** IDE. I like overall the idea of formatting my code after semicolon; when I try to write two lines of code in a straight line I cannot. Because when I enter/type the semicolon for the second line it automatically takes it to the next line.

Comment: The simple answer is to get into the habit of writing one statement per line. Multiple statements per line makes the code hard to read. Don't fight the editor!

Comment: It is doing automatic formating.
If you are not interested then turn it off. But its good habit to write each statement on new line as mentioned by @WeatherVane.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with you but lets just say that i am opening a file using a file pointer and after opening, i check if FilePointer is null, now it would be better to write it in the same line wouldn't it?

Comment: IMO you should start a code block, with `{` braces `}`. In very rare situations I might have a sequence of similar pairs of statements on one line, but is the exception. You should follow the style that other coders use, it is done for a reason. You'll also find that you can debug the code more easily with one statement per line.

Comment: Yeah, listen to @WeatherVane advice.  Writing code is easy, debugging is not and you need every advantage you can get.

Comment: You should add the code if you are giving examples. Telling about your code doesn't work. Also please look at `clang-format` it is an great example of good usable formatting.

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 5):

You can also configure auto-formatting with the following settings:

```
editor.formatOnSave - to format when you save your file.
editor.formatOnType - to format as you type (triggered on the ; character).
```

Follow the link to edit settings for Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide

You can turn off automatic formatting of Visual Studio IDE from Tools -> Options

[image]

Comment: That's VS and not Visual Studio Code, buy my guess falls more on the side of a bad tag since I don't believe VS Code has a similar option.

Comment: That's great to hear